# Android - Detecting when a view's constraints have been fully resolved/loaded

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, android-constraintlayout, android-xml

I have quite a complex problem to do with Android views. I am creating a paint application, and I have two views: a transparent background view and the pixel art board.

For both views, I want the height and width to be calculated off of the distance between view A and B:

[image]

Instead of calculating the distance between these two views, I simply 'constraint' a view in the middle like so, and then extract its height by using its `measuredHeight` property (and yes, you could also calculate the distance between view A and B in the code, but my problem still remains when I try that):

[image]

Now, here's the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/fragment_background_color_daynight"
    tools:context=".activities.canvas.CanvasActivity">
    <View
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_topView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/fragment_background_color_daynight"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.therealbluepandabear.pixapencil.customviews.colorswitcherview.ColorSwitcherView
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_colorSwitcherView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:isPrimarySelected="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activityCanvas_colorPickerRecyclerView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activityCanvas_topView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activityCanvas_colorPickerRecyclerView"
        app:primaryColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        app:secondaryColor="@color/black" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_colorPickerRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activityCanvas_topView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/activityCanvas_colorSwitcherView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/activityCanvas_primaryFragmentHost"
        tools:listitem="@layout/color_picker_layout" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_distanceContainer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activityCanvas_tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activityCanvas_primaryFragmentHost"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activityCanvas_topView" />

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:id="@+id/fragmentOuterCanvas_canvasFragmentHostCardViewParent"
        style="@style/activityCanvas_canvasFragmentHostCardViewParent_style"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activityCanvas_tabLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activityCanvas_topView">
        <!-- At runtime, the width and height will be calculated -->
       <com.therealbluepandabear.pixapencil.customviews.transparentbackgroundview.TransparentBackgroundView
            android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_transparentBackgroundView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_tabLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:tabStripEnabled="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/activityCanvas_viewPager2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activityCanvas_tab_tools_str" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activityCanvas_tab_filters_str" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activityCanvas_tab_color_palettes_str" />

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabItem
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/activityCanvas_tab_brushes_str" />
    </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_viewPager2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/activityCanvas_primaryFragmentHost"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activityCanvas_primaryFragmentHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Of course, when it comes to calculating, I thought it would be best practise to utilize AndroidX's `OneShotPreDrawListener`, like so:

```
OneShotPreDrawListener.add(binding.root) {
    binding.activityCanvasTransparentBackgroundView!!.setViewWidth(binding.activityCanvasDistanceContainer!!.measuredHeight)
    binding.activityCanvasTransparentBackgroundView!!.setViewHeight(binding.activityCanvasDistanceContainer!!.measuredHeight)
}
```

Now, for some reason, the result looks like so:

[image]

Why is this the case!

I did some debugging, and when I log the height of view C, I get the following:

[image]

This is wrong. So, as an experiment, I added a `GlobalLayoutListener` to detect *when* exactly the view's constraints get resolved:

```
binding.activityCanvasDistanceContainer?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnGlobalLayoutListener( object : ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    override fun onGlobalLayout() {
        Log.d("M_LOG", binding.activityCanvasDistanceContainer?.measuredHeight.toString())
    }
})
```

Result:

[image]

So, after the first couple of times it's 438, until after the 4th/5th time it shoots up to 1000.

I am really confused why this is happening, as I want to run the event when the constraints have been fully resolved and calculated, but using `OneShotPreDrawListener` (or any other alternative) is just running the event when the view has been drawn, but not yet when it has been positioned properly.

I am confused what to do. How can I run an event when the view's constraints have been fully calculated?

**Edit for Chetichamp:**

I have debugged this and I think I can reproduce this error and tell you in what scenario it occurs and in which scenario it does not.

Basically in my app, prior to activity creation, I have a fragment called `NewProjectFragment`, which looks like so:

[image]

Here's the code for when the 'Done' button is pressed:

```
binding.fragmentNewCanvasDoneButton.setOnClickListener {
    checkForTitleError()
    checkForWidthError()
    checkForHeightError()

    if (!invalidTitle && !invalidWidth && !invalidHeight) {
        try {
            val title =
                binding.fragmentNewCanvasProjectTitleTextInputEditText.text.toString()
            val widthValue: Int =
                binding.fragmentNewCanvasWidthTextInputEditText.text.toString().toInt()
            val heightValue: Int =
                binding.fragmentNewCanvasHeightTextInputEditText.text.toString().toInt()

            if (widthValue + heightValue >= 2000 && (requireActivity() as MainActivity).showLargeCanvasSizeWarning) {
                val frameLayout: FrameLayout =
                    this@setOnClickListeners.activity?.layoutInflater?.inflate(
                        R.layout.dont_show_large_canvas_warning_again_checkbox,
                        requireView().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                        false
                    )
                            as FrameLayout
                val checkBox = frameLayout.getChildAt(0) as MaterialCheckBox

                requireActivity().showDialog(
                    getString(R.string.generic_warning_in_code_str),
                    getString(R.string.dialog_large_canvas_warning_text_in_code_str),
                    getString(R.string.dialog_large_canvas_warning_positive_button_text_in_code_str),
                    { _, _ ->
                        if (checkBox.isChecked) {
                            (requireActivity() as MainActivity).showLargeCanvasSizeWarning =
                                false

                            with((requireActivity() as MainActivity).sharedPreferenceObject.edit()) {
                                putBoolean(
                                    StringConstants.Identifiers.SHARED_PREFERENCE_SHOW_LARGE_CANVAS_SIZE_WARNING_IDENTIFIER,
                                    (requireActivity() as MainActivity).showLargeCanvasSizeWarning
                                )
                                apply()
                            }
                        }

                        caller.onDoneButtonPressed(
                            title,
                            widthValue,
                            heightValue,
                            paramSpotLightInProgress
                        )
                    },
                    getString(R.string.dialog_unsaved_changes_negative_button_text_in_code_str),
                    { _, _ ->
                    },
                    frameLayout
                )
            } else {
                caller.onDoneButtonPressed(
                    title,
                    widthValue,
                    heightValue,
                    paramSpotLightInProgress
                )
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            HapticFeedbackWrapper.performHapticFeedback(binding.fragmentNewCanvasDoneButton)
        }
    } else {
        HapticFeedbackWrapper.performHapticFeedback(binding.fragmentNewCanvasDoneButton)
    }
}
```

As you can see, it has a listener, so the code for the listener, which is in `MainActivity`, is like so (maybe this is causing the issue? and I just don't need a listener like this? I don't know if you think this is why I get the issue):

```
fun MainActivity.extendedOnDoneButtonPressed(projectTitle: String, width: Int, height: Int, spotLightInProgress: Boolean) {
    startActivity(
        Intent(this, CanvasActivity::class.java)
            .putExtra(StringConstants.Extras.PROJECT_TITLE_EXTRA, projectTitle)
            .putExtra(StringConstants.Extras.WIDTH_EXTRA, width)
            .putExtra(StringConstants.Extras.HEIGHT_EXTRA, height)
            .putExtra(StringConstants.Extras.SPOTLIGHT_IN_PROGRESS_EXTRA, spotLightInProgress)
    )
}
```

Now, what I come to the conclusion is that all of this extra work is causing a delay, because when you simply tap on a pre-existing project, we can see that the intent is much simpler:

```
fun MainActivity.extendedOnCreationTapped(param: PixelArt) {
    startActivity(
        Intent(this, CanvasActivity::class.java)
            .putExtra(StringConstants.Extras.INDEX_EXTRA, pixelArtData.indexOf(param))
            .putExtra(StringConstants.Extras.PROJECT_TITLE_EXTRA, param.title))
}
```

With a simple intent like so, the problem **doesn't get reproduced, and it sizes properly.**

What I relaized is that the work done in `NewProject` fragment is causing a delay, and when I simply **scrap out the work** and perfom **a simple intent**, the problem is 'fixed'. I don't know how to fix this but hopefully it can help with finding a solution.

**Debugging even further**

When I debug the issue even further, I notice something strange. The measuredHeight of the root layout jumps up by one thousand:

[image]

This is not observed when the creation is tapped with the simple intent. I am lost for words as to how strange this bug is, I've never seen this in my life.

Comment: In the one-shot, you are setting the width to the measured height. Is that what you want to do? Also, what are the definitions of `setWidth()` and `setHeight()`?

Comment: @Cheticamp the actual calculations of the width/height are complex, but they do utilize / act upon the width/height of the constrainted view to ensure that the custom view fits properly and doesn't 'overflow' on devices with a larger ui size or tablets.

Comment: @Cheticamp I don't have those methods. If you mean `setViewWidth`, it just sets the size in the onMeasure overriden method or something. It's not important. The real issue  I am having is that OneShot is being called before all constraint calculations are done and thus the only way to get the desired effect/expected result is to wait after 4-5 calls of on predraw, which is extremely inpractical and error prone. I am in great need of assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow guys.

I finally found a solution, after 12 hours of nonstop debugging, almost going clinically insane, and logging and destroying my codebase.

I realized that the keyboard from the `NewProjectFragment` was cutting the view, causing the bug. Holy moly... I am ecstatic that I finally found why this is happening but at the same time shocked how I didn't discover this before!

The solution was to add the following to the activity:

```
     <activity
            android:name="com.therealbluepandabear.pixapencil.activities.canvas.CanvasActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" // this
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" 
            android:exported="false" />
```

Prior to this, the `windowSoftInputMode` was `adjustResize` -- causing the bug.

Answer (score 0):

There is something going on with your code that is touching your views that is causing the multiple layouts. Without that code being posted, it is impossible to say what.

To help you with debugging, set the one shot to the following:

```
OneShotPreDrawListener.add(binding.root) {
    Log.d("Applog", "OneShot")
    binding.activityCanvasTransparentBackgroundView.layoutParams.width =
        binding.activityCanvasDistanceContainer.measuredWidth
    binding.activityCanvasTransparentBackgroundView.layoutParams.height =
        binding.activityCanvasDistanceContainer.measuredHeight
    binding.activityCanvasTransparentBackgroundView.requestLayout()
}
```

In my test, when placing this in the `onCreateView()` function of a fragment, "OneShot" is logged just once and the size of the view is adjusted as you say it should be. (btw, `requestLayout()` was required in this test.)

I would take a look at any other code that touches your views to see if something else is triggering the multiple calls: maybe `setWidth()` or `setHeight()`.

---

---

I will add that I have noticed in the past that *ConstraintLayout* will call the global layout listener multiple times. Usually, I would say, the listener is removed on the first call, so this behavior would not be noticed.

Instead of the global layout listener or the predraw listener, you could try a layout listener:

```
binding.root.doOnLayout {
    // Your code here
}
```

or

```
binding.root.doOnNextLayout {
    // Your code here
}
```

`doOnNextLayout` is guaranteed to be called only once, while `doOnLayout` may be called multiple times.

Comment: Appreciate the answer, but `requestLayout` is being called in the set functions. I'll take a look at your other recommendations. I'm not aware of any code that is touching the views, but I'll take another look. Thanks.

Comment: The `doOnLayout` and `doOnNextLayout` isn't working, thanks though.

Comment: A weird caveat is that it does work if I load a pixel art project that has already been created, but doesn't if I load a new one. Something must be going on, but I just can't figure out _what_ exactly.

Comment: Something with the intents is causing the delay, from what I've seen so far.

Comment: There is more going on that you haven't posted. If you can reduce the issue to a set of code that can reproduce the probelem ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), that would help you to get an answer.